# New .accessibilityAddTraits(.isToggle) not working on Xcode 15

Tags: swiftui, accessibility

I'm using Xcode 15 15A5160n, and can't seem to get `.accessibilityAddTraits(.isToggle)` working.

I use the code from WWDC https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10036/:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FilterButton: View {
    @State var filter: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { filter.toggle() }) {
            Text("Filter")
        }
        .background(filter ? .gray : .green)
        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isToggle)
    }
}

#Preview {
    FilterButton()
}
```

and I put it into a `ContentView`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            FilterButton()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

When I run and open accessibility inspector (Version 5.0 (142)) I select the simulator and target the button.

It reads "filter unchecked switch" yet in the video I see they say "Filter Switch Button". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to make a button and add that style to a toggle

```
struct ToggleButtonStyle: ToggleStyle {
     var isOn: Bool
     func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("filter")
        }.background(configuration.isOn ? .grey : .green)
    
    }
}
struct ToggleButton: View {
   @State private var isOn = false

  var body: some View {
      Toggle("Filter", isOn: $isOn)
          .toggleStyle(ToggleButtonStyle(isOn: false))
  }
}
```